# Scope access passport-jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-jwt

Can someone explain to me in detail why the route of /profile has access to the user object. I'm currently learning JavaScript and NodeJS your answer will be a big help in my learning Thank you guys.

```
app.post('/login',function (req, res) {
        let email = req.body.email;
        let password = req.body.password;
        User.getUserByEmail(email, (err, user) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            if (!user) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: "User not found!"
                });
            }
            User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                    var token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.JWT_SECRET, {
                        expiresIn: '15m'
                    });
                    res.json({
                        success: true,
                        token: token,
                        user: {
                            id: user._id,
                            email: user.email
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    return res.json({
                        success: false,
                        message: "Password incorrect!"
                    });
                }
            })
        });
    });

    app.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
        session: false
    }), (req, res) => {
        res.json({user: req.user});
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your `passport.authenticate()` call populates `user` to `req`.

**From passports.org:**

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

It is the same for your route, except your path and authentication method is different.

See the documentation for more info: http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

Answer (score 0):

## Some background

- The function [`app.get`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.get.method) takes an `url` and **one or many** callbacks with `(req, res, next) => {}` as their signature
- The *callbacks* are executed one after the other. In anyone of these *callbacks* **you can modify the `req` object** and it will *"propagate"* to the next callbacks
- To switch from a callback to the next one, you call `next`

## In your case

- The call to `passport.authenticate('jwt', {sessions: false})` returns a *callback*, that's executed before you send the `json` response.
- That callback itself *athenticates* the user, then *"inject"* its value into the `req` object.
- As I mentioned before, this `req` will *"propagate"* to the next callback. And that's why when you send your `json` response, it `req` already contains the `user` key